# How to install WSL on Windows 10 Education

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am having difficulty installing WSL. I have enabled "Developer Mode," but when I go to Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off, Windows Subsystem for Linux is not listed.

I have tried running the following command in an admin PowerShell, but it hangs indefinitely (or, at least, for a few hours) about 5% of the way through:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux`

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Super User.  What is your Windows "Version" and "System Type" from System Information?  I'm not familiar with the Education builds, but they should follow closely with Enterprise/Pro.  Developer Mode hasn't been needed to turn it on in about 5 years or so.

Comment: My Windows version should be the latest. The version is "Version 10.0.19043 Build 19043." It is an Intel x64 PC.